# Easier way to write if val = for multiple functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

fiddle - http://jsbin.com/oJUMIjUj/1/edit

```
// Autocomplete Search
$(".talk").on('keyup change', function() {
  var $val = $(this).val();

  if($val === "Say Hi") {
    alert('Ello Mate!');
  }


  if($val === "Say Bye") {
    alert('Bye Bye');
  }
});
```

Because this function is case sensitive relying on a text input type. Is there any easier way to write this function?

examples...

```
if($val === "Say Hi", "Say Bye", "say hi", "say bye", "Hi", "Bye") {
  alert('Ello Mate!');
}

if($val === "Say Hi", $val === "Say Bye", $val === "say hi", $val === "say bye", $val === "Hi", $val === "Bye") {
  alert('Ello Mate!');
}
```

Comment: You are alerting two different `String`s in the first function, yet alerting the same `String` in the second.  Can you give a better explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Just a simpler way to write these functions, instead of individual if val === this functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoke the function [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) on `$val` in the comparison.

```
  if($val.toLowerCase() === "save") {
    saveTextAsFile();
  }
```

Comment: @mikethedj4 I will take a look, but you changed the entire question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray) with an array of possible values, the following will satisfy for any one of the 4 cases

```
if ($.inArray($val.toLowerCase(), ["say hi", "say bye", "hi", "bye"]) > -1) {
    alert('Ello Mate!');
}
```

Comment: Thank you this has been helpful.